# using querySelector instead of document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

should I replace `document.getElementById` or so by `document.querySelector`?
any difference?

Will you recommend me to use `querySelector`?

Comment: Whether you can use `querySelector()` (or `querySelectorAll()`) depends entirely on your users having browsers that implment that method, and on your own specific use-case. Have you experienced a problem using, or *not* using, `querySelector()`?

Answer (score 3):

When you are selecting on ids anyway, use `getElementById` as that’s a lot more efficient than using `querySelector` on an id selector. The latter runs the whole CSS selector parsing, while the former can just take the ID and get the element with that ID directly.

Of course, when selecting based on other criteria than the element’s id, `querySelector` (and `querySelectorAll`) obviously has its place.

(The [obligatory benchmark](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector) to prove this claim, although I do want to note that benchmarks are not everything, and the difference probably won’t make much difference in an actual application.)

Answer (score 0):

If `querySelector` is available in the browser that your users use. Then you can use it. It is nice to not have to litter your html with ids. Selecting using css selectors is extremely flexible.

Performance is a red herring. My shitty old laptop can manage 3 million selections a second...

The real problem is compatibility. How are you going to deal with browsers that don't have it available? Do you care? You probably have to care.

Answer (score 0):

Both serves same purpose in your case. But `getElementById` is most proven approach. However, if you are not concerned about legacy browsers then `querySelector` will also suffice.

Enjoy!